# Delete hits on elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm traing to delete an element of colection "territorial_zone_all"

This is my POST request maked with the help of the documentation

```
curl --location 'https://mypage.com/elastic/territorial_zone_all/_delete_by_query' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_id":"yAq5An8BkOYqFwborrlp"
    }
  }
}'
```

but allwais returnt to me **Cannot POST /elastic/territorial_zone_all/_delete_by_query** I have been try with DELETE AND GET metho but return to me 404.

Comment: What is `https://mypage.com/elastic/`? Is it your application or wrapper around elasticsearch? Are you sure it can pass this request to elasticsearch?

Comment: This is my url to consult elastic information, for example the url `https://mypage.com/elastic/territorial_zone_all`
return to me the collection of territorial_zone_all

Comment: It might be a proxy that only passes through certain GET and POST requests and block all DELETE requests. You should talk to the person who installed it.

Answer (score 0):

To delete an element of collection `territorial_zone_all`, you need to get the `_index`, `_type` and `_id` of the document that needs to be deleted from index `territorial_zone_all`.

Once you get this value, all you need to do is run the following curl:

```
curl --location --request DELETE '{host}/{_index}/{_type}/{_id}' \
--data-raw ''
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I modified the curl to the next example, but i got the same result.
CURL : `{host}/elastic/territorial_zone_all/_doc/yAq5An8BkOYqFwborrlp`
RESULT: **Cannot POST /elastic/territorial_zone_all/_doc/yAq5An8BkOYqFwborrlp**
I did it with DELETE method but get the same result, thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to re-check the host, `https://mypage.com/elastic/` is this the url where elastic is hosted ? The rest of your path looks good to me.